# Cannot extract all data from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with four entries and I am simply trying to read all the entries made in database. But no matter whatever I try the first entry won't show up.

Output for `select * from userdata` :

```
+-----------+-----------+
| username  | password  |
+-----------+-----------+
| admin     | admin     |
| arush     | arush     |
| root      | root      |
| superuser | superuser |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Output from my php code :

```
arush arush
root root
superuser superuser
SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...This Completed
```

PHP Code :

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM userdata")
        or die(mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['password'];
            echo "\n";
        }
        if(!empty($row['username']) and !empty($row['password'])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['password']; 
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE..."; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
        }
```

and as I suppose, because the first row is not shown or blank the `!empty($row['username']) and !empty($row['password'])` condition check is also failing.

p.s: sorry if it seems to be a no sense question, am totally new to PHP and wasn't able to find any relative similar question.

Comment: `mysql_error()` <= that's mixing btw. Use its `i` equivalent.

Comment: thats odd, you are selecting all rows in this `SELECT * FROM userdata`, should you be expecting just 1 row instead?

Comment: @Ghost well yea, right but this actually is a test code. Since the whole login mechanism was failing, so I decided to test and see what all data I am able to extract. So that based on the result I can figure out what's wrong is going in there and plan accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling `$row = mysqli_fetch_array()` twice in a row, overwriting the first record before it is ever printed. That is why "admin" never shows up.

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); // this puts the admin record in $row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) // this overwrites $row with the next record (root)
```

You do not need the first line in this snippet as it gets executed and checked before the body of the `while` loop is entered.

Comment: Yea that worked !! Thank you so much. But the `!empty($row['username']) and !empty($row['password'])` condition check is still failing.

Answer (score 1):

Think that you need to:

1) Use || instead 'or' and && instead 'and'

2) Use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead mysqli_fetch_array

3) You need to create independent variables like $username, $password, Then, in while iteration do a check and if it's true - assign username and password to these variables.

After while iteration put something like:

```
if(strlen($row['username']) > 0 && strlen($row['password']) > 0)
```

instead

```
if(!empty($row['username']) and !empty($row['password']))
```

4) use simple debug, like: var_dump($variable); die('debug point');

Finaly, debug everything. If you debug line after while iterator you will see that $row variable equals null, so you get error.
(in future: xdebug will be your best friend in programm debugging)